# Fallo en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

No sé si es por la última actualización de Wordpress, pero el backend está dando problemas.

Al intentar acceder a un plugin ([Contact form 7](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)) me aparece esto:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in ...
```

Y aquí empiezan unas rutas de archivos. ¿Alguien puede darme alguna pista?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que ese plugin está usando las funciones `mysql_*` que han sido deprecadas/desaprobadas ([en PHP 5.5](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)) y eliminadas completamente ([a partir de PHP 7.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql)).

Si actualizaste wordpress o el servidor, seguramente se haya actualizado la versión de PHP y se haya eliminado el soporte a las funciones `mysql_*` y el plugin haya dejado de funcionar por eso. Una posible solución sería actualizar a la última versión del plugin, que seguramente esté adaptada ya a los nuevos requerimientos.

Comment: Comprendo, creo que podré solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!